# PNG IDAT specification

Tags: image, image-processing, png, encode

I'm going over the W3 PNG specification (creating a PNG library from scratch) and I've finally found how to create a green 1x1 image.

Now I'm trying to create a bigger image of mixed Red, Green and Blue pixels. Let's say a 4x4 image. Sadly I'm getting all the pixels mixed and some of them are Black or Pink.

Details:

- Signature: OK
- IHDR: OK

  - Width: 4
  - Heigh: 4
  - Bit depth: 8
  - Color: 2
  - Filter: 0
  - Compression: 0
  - Interlace: 0
- IDATA: 4 chunks*
- IEND: OK

*IDATA chunks:

- 4 bytes length: Number of bytes of the DATA after Zlib deflate
- 4*1 byte type: IDAT
- X bytes data: 4*4bytes unsigned integers, Zlib deflated, one after the other, Network byte order

  - 255 for blue**
  - 65280 for green**
  - 16711680 for red**
- 4 bytes crc: OK

**Bitwise results of:

```
alpha<<24 | red<<16 | green<<8 | blue
```

With alpha, blue, green and red taking values from 0 to 255

What's wrong with this?

Comment: This question was cross-posted to DSP, so I copied my answer there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The PNG pixels are in RGBA order, not ARGB, so you'd need to write

```
alpha | red<<24 | green << 16 | blue <<8
```

But you are writing color type 2, so your pixels should be 3 bytes each
instead of four; you can't really encode them in 4-byte integers
as you've done.  So either change the color type to 6 or switch
to writing each sample as an individual byte.

Also you need a filter byte at the beginning of each row.  Zero will work
for you.  So in your example 4x4 RGB image you will need to write 13 bytes per
row

```
0 R G B R G B R G B R G B
0 R G B R G B R G B R G B
0 R G B R G B R G B R G B
0 R G B R G B R G B R G B
```

then concatenate all the row bytes into one byte stream and zlib-compress that.  It can all go into one IDAT chunk.  If you need to write smaller IDAT chunks, you have to zlib-compress the image first, then split the zlib output into pieces that you put in consecutive IDAT chunks.

Comment: Great explanation. I'll try it right away. About rows... I guess they will be rendered based on the image width, is that right? So I just need to write these 13bytes groups one right after the other

Comment: Yes, just concatenate your row bytes into one long stream and send that to zlib.